# Two questions about expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

The next two facts are basic but I've been having trouble understanding them theoretically. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables, then

**first fact**: $X\leq Y$ a.s. implies $E[X]\leq E[Y]$;

**second fact**: $E_{X}[X+Y]=E_{X}[X]+Y$, where $E_{X}$ means the expected values with respect to $X$.

Note that the two facts are very vague. The first one does not indicate where the random variables are defined, i.e., in which probability space. The second one is not clear about de definition of $E_{X}$.

I'm not defining $E_{X}$ because I have never seen a proper definition. Furthermore, $E_{X}$ should work for other transformations, e.g., $E_{X}[XY]=YE_{X}[X]$.

I think that the answer should involve product measure. Let $(S_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)$, $i=1,2$, be two probability spaces and $(S,\Sigma,\mu)=(S_2,\Sigma_2,\mu_2)\times (S_2,\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ with de proper definition of the cartesian product of two measure spaces. Now define $(X,Y)\in(S,\Sigma,\mu)$.

Can I answer the two questions studying objects like 
\begin{align}
Z(s_1) := \int_{S_2}g(X(s_1),Y(s_2))\mu_2(ds_2)
\end{align}
where I can take $g(x,y)=x$ for the first fact and $g(x,y)=x+y$ for the second? Is there any problem with the mesurability of $Z$?

Comment: If the meaning is clear (like in the statement of fact 1), one usually omits the probability space from statements of theorems (at least in my experience). Indeed, saying $X\leq Y$ a.s. means that for (almost) all $\omega\in \Omega$, $X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)$ which implies $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same space.

Comment: There is no definition of “expected value with respect to X” as you suggest.  (So your second “fact” does not make sense). Some papers might use that notation only to remind you what is random and what is not. It would make sense either if $Y$ is constant or if you change to conditional expectation given $Y$.

Comment: A simple way to think about fact 1 is to first convince yourself that if $Z$ is a nonnegative random variable then $E[Z]\geq 0$. Then define $Z=Y-X$.

Comment: @AdamMartens You are right. I'm always having trouble with the definition of a random variable and how to characterize its distributions.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it doesn't make sense to me either. I think that the answer is that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then you define for example $E_{X,Y}[.]=E_{X}[E_{Y}[.|X]]$. It's just an abuse of notation I think.